# When converting an infix expression to prefix using stacks, if the scanned and top of the stack operators have same precedence, what should be done?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

This question was asked in a single choice MCQ test. While scanning an infix expression to convert to prefix, if the scanned operator and the operator at the top of the stack have the same order of precedence, what should be the course of action?

The two options that made the most sense were:

1. Simply push the incoming operator on to the stack.
2. Pop the present operator on top of the stack and add it to the converted expression and then push the incoming operator on to the stack again.

The answer as told by the instructor is option 1. However my answer was option 2. Both lines of thinking would yield different results:

Say we have an infix expression a * b * c. If we go by method 1, it yields the prefix expression **abc. If we go by option 2, it yields the result  * a * bc.

So what is the right answer?

(This is the algorithm I used to answer this question: http://scanftree.com/Data_Structure/infix-to-prefix The confusion is at the part where operators of equal order of precedence get involved.)

Comment: Just because they are unary operators, they don't need to (and have not) the same preceedence.

Comment: Corrected that. The textbook I refer mentions they do have the same order of precedence (++ and * and also &) and so the evaluation is done from right to left..am I missing something?

Comment: It does not tell the whole truth. Anyway, `*p++` has versy different semantics from `++*p` or even `*++p`. You might want to get a better textbook.

Comment: Okay. I will remove that example. But I think the question holds even without that example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the associativity of the operators. Some operators are left-associative. For example, 2-3-4 should be interpreted as (2-3)-4, not as 2-(3-4). Other operators are right-associative. For example, in C, x=y=z should be interpreted as x=(y=z), not as (x=y)=z.

Comment: This makes sense. So what would be the right approach to convert to prefix by still keeping associativity in mind?

Comment: @PriyankarKumar you have enumwrated two possible answers. use answer 1 for left associative operators and answer 2 for right associative operators.